# "undefined local variable or method" when starting production server

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I try to start my app in a production server I get the error:

```
/users_controller.rb:3: undefined local variable or method `signup_url' for UsersController:Class (NameError)
```

the code referenced is in my users_controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  if User.find(:all).empty?
    redirect_to signup_url, :notice => "Please make the first Administrator account."
  else
    before_filter :authorize
    before_filter :office_or_admin_only
  end
```

in my routes.rb

```
match 'signup' => 'users#new', :as => :signup
```

It all works just fine in development. This is the first time running the production server, I created and raked the production db, but I have made to changes to any files in my app. Is there some magic line I need to put in a config file to run production mode? Or is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: I doubt that the code you pasted includes line 3 of users_controller. If this route is being reference elsewhere in your controller, please paste that instead.

Comment: Where is your production environment hosted?

Comment: Try using `link_to :signup` instead, the issue may be that you matched the route to `:signup` but you're still calling it using the standard helper

Comment: updated to indeed show that the redirect is line 3. Production is hosted on Webrick localhost:3000

Comment: `link_to :signup` results in no method link_to

Answer (score 1):

No idea why it was presenting this way, but... here's what the problem was.

I had a recursive loop, the source of which was line 3 above.

I fixed it like this:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  if User.find(:all).empty?
    before_filter :authorize, :except => [:create, :new]
  else
    before_filter :authorize
    before_filter :office_or_admin_only
  end
```

application_controller.rb

```
def authorize
  unless User.find_by_id(session[:user_id])
    if User.find(:all).empty?
      redirect_to signup_url, :notice => "Please make the first Administrator account."
    else
      redirect_to login_url
    end
  end
end
```

This makes everything redirect to the sign_up url when the users table is empty, but avoids the recursive filtering by adding an exception to the filter for the methods called with the sign_up url when the users table is empty.

I figured this out by resetting the db in development to make the conditions the same as the attempted production conditions. The server started just fine, but my browser told me I had a recursive loop when navigating to localhost:3000.

Comment: Take home message: reset your db from time to time to make sure your app works from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Try `link_to :signup` or `link_to new_user_path`